# How to know the first ran jobId of a cached query in big-query?

Tags: google-bigquery

When we run a query in big-query environment, the results are cached in the temporary table. From next time onwards, when we ran the same query multiple times, the subsequent runs will fetch the results from the cache for the next 24 hrs with some exceptions. Now my use case is, in the subsequent runs, i want to know like from which jobId this query cache results are got, previous first time run of the query ??

I have checked all the java docs related to query didn't find that info. We have [cacheHit](https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.82.0/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobStatistics.QueryStatistics.html#getCacheHit--) variable, which will tell you whether the query has fetched from the cache or not . Here i want to know one step further, from what jobId, the results got fetched. I expected like, may be in this [method](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobStatistics#com_google_cloud_bigquery_JobStatistics_getParentJobId__) i can know the info, but i am always getting the null value for that. I also want to know what is meant by parentJob in big-query  context.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you'd even care about this other than as a technical exercise.  If you want to build your own application caching layer that's a different concern.  More details about query caching can be found on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results.

The easiest way to do this would probably be by traversing `jobs.list` until you find a job that has the same destination table (it'll be prefaced with an `anon` prefix), and where the `cacheHit` stat is false/not present.

Your inquiry about `parentJob` is unrelated to this exercise.  It's for finding all the child jobs created as part of a script or multi-statement execution.  More information about this can be found on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts.

Comment: To give you the context, i am working on a monitoring system, for the first time when query was ran, we can see the dataset name ,stage details and other granular details. From the next time when the same query has ran, then we are not able to see those details, if we have a way to link the cached query with original query then it will be more clear to the end user , so for that i am checking whether the google is providing those details (first run JOBID details )   . Yeah if the google is not providing that, then we have to go in a way which you suggested

Comment: You may be better served from using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA jobs tables to do this in the aggregate rather than using the API for stitching this together piecemeal: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs